# Discrepancies in size of area for Brownian bridge model

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, sf, movement-data

I want to get the size of some animal tracks using a Brownian bridge movement model. However, I've noticed that when I combine my data into a single object the size of the area differs compared to when I model the animals separately.

I could replicate this using an online data set based on mule deer which I show below. You can see that when combined the area for D8 is around 30km2 but is ~21km2 when modelled alone.

```
library(move)
library(sf)
library(amt)

muleys <-
  read.csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walterASEL/Walter-Datasets/master/Exercise_4.6_dBBMM/muleysexample.csv"
  )
str(muleys)

#TIME DIFF ONLY NECESSARY AS A MEANS EXCLUDE POOR DATA LATER
muleys$Date <- as.numeric(muleys$GPSFixTime)
timediff <- diff(muleys$Date) * 24 * 60
muleys <- muleys[-1, ]
muleys$timediff <- as.numeric(abs(timediff))

#FOR ALL DEER
muleys$DT <-
  as.POSIXct(strptime(muleys$GPSFixTime, format = '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS'))
muleys$DT

#Sort data to address error in code
muleys <- muleys[order(muleys$id, muleys$DT), ]
summary(muleys$id)

#EXCLUDE OUTLIERS AND POOR DATA FIXES
newmuleys <-
  subset(muleys, muleys$Long > -110.90 & muleys$Lat > 37.80)
muleys <- newmuleys
newmuleys <- subset(muleys, muleys$Long < -107)
muleys <- newmuleys

#Create a move object for all deer using the Move package
loc <-
  move(
    x = muleys$X,
    y = muleys$Y,
    time = as.POSIXct(muleys$GPSFixTime,
                      format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"),
    proj = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83"),
    data = muleys,
    animal = muleys$id
  )

#Now create a dBBMM object
two_dbbmm <-
  brownian.bridge.dyn(
    object = loc,
    location.error = 22,
    window.size = 19,
    margin = 7,
    dimSize = 100,
    time.step = 180
  )
plot(two_dbbmm)

st_area(hr_isopleths(two_dbbmm$D12, level = 1.0)) / 1e6 #' 0.08170328
st_area(hr_isopleths(two_dbbmm$D8, level = 1.0)) / 1e6 #' 29.85663

#or select a single deer
dataD8 <- subset(muleys, muleys$id == "D8")
dataD8$id <- droplevels.factor(dataD8$id)
#dataD8 <- muleys
d8 <-
  move(
    x = dataD8$X,
    y = dataD8$Y,
    time = as.POSIXct(dataD8$GPSFixTime, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"),
    proj = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83"),
    data = dataD8,
    animal = dataD8$id
  )
d8_dbbmm <-
  brownian.bridge.dyn(
    object = d8,
    location.error = 22,
    window.size = 19,
    margin = 7,
    dimSize = 100,
    time.step = 180
  )
st_area(hr_isopleths(d8_dbbmm$layer, level = 1.0)) / 1e6 #' 20.64832
```